# Show that $3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 2$ is equal to the number of sets of rank at most $2$ with a $3$-valued notion of set membership

Tags: combinatorics, logic, set-theory, cardinals

*This question is with regard to the answer of an [older post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187917/is-it-possible-to-define-higher-cardinal-arithmetics/247795#247795). Please see the original post's answer for context.*

The following answer was given to a question about what the tetration $k \!\uparrow\uparrow\! n$ is actually counting, where

$$‎k \!\uparrow\uparrow\! n := \underbrace{k^{k^{k^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}_{n - times}.$$

> $k \!\uparrow\uparrow\! n$ is equal to the number of sets of rank at most $n$ when we adopt a $k$-valued notion of set membership.
>
> For example, this view still gives us one set of rank $0$, namely the empty set $\{\}$, but now we have $k$ sets of rank $0$ or $1$, namely the sets containing only $\{\}$, with value between $0$ and $k-1$ (of course, the set containing $\{\}$ with value $0$ is identified with $\{\}$, so that we only get $k-1$ new sets of rank $1$, for a total of $k$ with rank $0$ or $1$). It is easy to check that we get $k^k$ "sets" of rank at most $2$, $k^{k^k}$ of rank at most $3$, and $k \!\uparrow\uparrow\! n$ sets of rank at most $n$.

**My problem:**

It is easy to write out the sets for $3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 0$ and $3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 1$, as they are simply

\begin{align}
3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 0 \ \ &: \ \ \{ \} \\ 
3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 1 \ \ &: \ \ \{ \}, \big\{ \{ \}_{1}\big\}, \big\{ \{ \}_{2}\big\} 
\end{align}
where each subscript indicates the intrinsic value of the member; however, I struggle to follow the described pattern for the 27 members that should be associated with $‎3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 2$.

**Points will be awarded to the first answer that can correctly list all 27 members of $3 \!\uparrow\uparrow\! 2$, as described in the OP.**

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1.

Comment: All the more unsure about that since it has since received five +1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set has rank at most $n$ iff each of its members has rank at most $n-1$. Therefore, each set of rank at most $n$ corresponds to a choice of one of the $k$ membership values for each set of rank at most $n-1$. This means our counting function $f$ satisfies $f(n, k)=k^{f(n-1,k)}$, from which we can conclude that $f(n,k)=k\!\uparrow\uparrow\!n$.

If your three sets of rank at most $1$ are denoted $A$, $B$, and $C$, then the $3^3$ sets of rank at most $2$ are:

$\{A_0,B_0,C_0\},\{A_0,B_0,C_1\},\{A_0,B_0,C_2\},$

$\{A_0,B_1,C_0\},\{A_0,B_1,C_1\},\{A_0,B_1,C_2\},$

$\{A_0,B_2,C_0\},\{A_0,B_2,C_1\},\{A_0,B_2,C_2\},$

$\{A_1,B_0,C_0\},\{A_1,B_0,C_1\},\{A_1,B_0,C_2\},$

...

$\{A_2,B_2,C_0\},\{A_2,B_2,C_1\},\{A_2,B_2,C_2\}$

where subscript $0$ denotes non-membership, so e.g. $\{A_0,B_0,C_0\}=\{\}$.